# Determine customer with most orders placed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have working with two tables in sql developer to determine which customer has placed the most orders I have gotten as far as to figure out the total number of order placed by each customer, but cannot figure out how to show only the one with the MAX number of orders...

For example- 
this will give me a list of all customers who placed orders and the number of orders each of them have placed

```
 SELECT 
  customer.cust_num, customer.cust_bizname,
  COUNT(invoice.inv_num) AS "TOTAL ORDERS"
FROM customer INNER JOIN invoice ON customer.cust_num = invoice.cust_num
GROUP BY customer.cust_num, customer.cust_bizname;
```

If I attempt to use max and count together...

```
 SELECT 
      customer.cust_num, customer.cust_bizname,
      MAX(COUNT(invoice.inv_num)) AS "TOTAL ORDERS"
    FROM customer INNER JOIN invoice ON customer.cust_num = invoice.cust_num
    GROUP BY customer.cust_num, customer.cust_bizname;
```

I get an error stating "not a single-group group function".
 How can I effectively count the number of orders and display only the customer that has placed the highest number of orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `max` like that. Instead, order by count in descending order and get the first record, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM
(select customer.cust_num, customer.cust_bizname,
  COUNT(invoice.inv_num) AS "TOTAL ORDERS"
FROM customer INNER JOIN invoice ON customer.cust_num = invoice.cust_num
GROUP BY customer.cust_num, customer.cust_bizname
ORDER BY "TOTAL ORDERS" desc)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Order BY` with `ROWNUM`

```
select * 
from
(SELECT customer.cust_num, 
        customer.cust_bizname,
        COUNT(invoice.inv_num) AS "TOTAL ORDERS"
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN invoice 
ON customer.cust_num = invoice.cust_num
GROUP BY customer.cust_num, customer.cust_bizname
Order by "TOTAL ORDERS" DESC
)
Where ROWNUM =1
```

or Use `Row_Number()` Analytic Function

```
select customer.cust_num, 
       customer.cust_bizname,
       "TOTAL ORDERS"
FROM
(
SELECT Row_number() over(order by COUNT(invoice.inv_num) DESC) As RN
        customer.cust_num, 
        customer.cust_bizname,
        COUNT(invoice.inv_num) AS "TOTAL ORDERS"
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN invoice 
ON customer.cust_num = invoice.cust_num
GROUP BY customer.cust_num, customer.cust_bizname
)
Where RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12, you can use the ANSI standard `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
SELECT c.cust_num, c.cust_bizname, COUNT(i.inv_num) AS "TOTAL ORDERS"
FROM customer c INNER JOIN
     invoice i
     ON c.cust_num = i.cust_num
GROUP BY c.cust_num, c.cust_bizname
ORDER BY COUNT(i.inv_num) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```